# auto-startup="false" causing to exit the process

Tags: spring, integration, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-rabbit

We have been using auto-startup="true" every thing works fine. We have been using Controlbus to start/stop the adapter. We have to change the auto-startup="false" then start the Adapter using Control bus. auto-startup="false" is causing the process to stop (it is not up and running).

How we can me the process running but just stop the inbound-channel-adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't exit from `main()`, or fire up a non-daemon thread.